# Cron Error : chdir failed (/usr/share/httpd): - Using Nginx

Tags: nginx, crontab, centos-7, webmin

```
(CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/usr/share/httpd): No such file or directory
```

I checked the log and found the following error.
Why does cron tries to change the directory?

I am not using httpd. I am using nginx.
I am using webmin.

Answer (score 1):

That user [needs its home directory to exist](https://serverfault.com/questions/417850/why-isnt-my-cronjob-running#comment444230_418268), i.e.: `mkdir /usr/share/httpd`. Otherwise cron will keep complaining.

Comment: Will it give any trouble to the running website? (making a httpd directory?)

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. Website became unstable after creating that directory. I guess cron is locking php-fpm. I am not able to access the site for few seconds. then works. and then i am not able to access